# How do I update a path when using Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to install this Python application (https://github.com/NVIDIA/tacotron2/) and do not understand a required installation step.

I think that the instructions are asking me to specify a path, but I don't know how to do this.

Update `.wav` paths:

```
$ sed -i -- 's,DUMMY,ljs_dataset_folder/wavs,g' filelists/*.txt
```

After updating the .wav paths, the user is then instructed to:

> Install PyTorch 1.0
>   Install python requirements or build docker image
>
> Install python requirements: pip install -r requirements.txt

But I am still stumped by the instruction to update the `.wav` path.

Comment: Looks like there is a good explaination in a previous issue in the repo: https://github.com/NVIDIA/tacotron2/issues/43

Comment: You're right; I didn't register it, but this pretty much answers my query. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

What the [`sed`](http://booki.flossmanuals.net/command-line/sed) command does is:

- Open all `.txt` files in the `filelists` directory.
- Replace all occurences of `DUMMY` with `ljs_dataset_folder/wavs`
- Save the modified `.txt` file.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

the steps are self-explanatory 
Update .wav paths:

> sed -i -- 's,DUMMY,ljs_dataset_folder/wavs,g' filelists/*.txt

SED command in UNIX is stands for stream editor and it can perform lot’s of function on file like, searching, find and replace, insertion or deletion. Though most common use of SED command in UNIX is for substitution or for find and replace. By using SED you can edit files even without opening it, which is much quicker way to find and replace something in file, than first opening that file in VI Editor and then changing it.
OR

> ```
>  Alternatively, set load_mel_from_disk=True in hparams.py and update mel-spectrogram paths
> ```

https://github.com/NVIDIA/tacotron2/blob/master/hparams.py line26th

You can download the The LJ Speech Dataset from https://keithito.com/LJ-Speech-Dataset/ and put this into a folder named ljs_dataset_folder or anything of your choice.

Comment: Would I have to use the full file path? e.g:
sed -i -- 's,DUMMY,C:/Users/Me/Downloads/ljs_dataset_folder/wavs,g' filelists/*.txt